# Better and concise way of writing this regex pattern to examine conjoined occurrence of these phrases?

Tags: python, regex

```
pat = str('(?=.*University)(?=.*Business)|(?=.*School)(?=.*Business)|'
'(?=.*University)(?=.*Management)|(?=.*School)(?=.*Management)')
```

This will match things like NYU School of Business; Johnson School of Management. Both University/School and Management or University/School and Management have to be there.

The better solution doesn't have to be a regex pattern. If there's a way to do this using `in`, for instance, I'd be much appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place alternations (`…|…`) inside of the lookaheads (`(?=…)`) like this:

```
(?=.*(University|School))(?=.*(Business|Management))
```

This pattern will match any string that contains either `University` or `School` and either `Business` or `Management`.

Of course, this doesn't have to be done with a regex. You can do something like this:

```
if ("University" in string or "School" in string) and ("Business" in string or "Management" in string):
    ...
```